# Meteor: Clear form after submit using Angular2

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, forms, meteor

I'm trying to make my form clear itself after submitting an entry to my database, following this [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/forms-and-events). This is my code:

HTML:

```
<form class="new-task" ng-submit="$ctrl.addTask($crtl.newTask)";>
    <input ng-model="$crtl.newTask" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" minlength="1"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
addTask(newTask) {
    // Insert a task into the collection
    Tasks.insert({
        text: newTask,
        createdAt: new Date
    });

    // Clear form
    this.newTask = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo, should've been

```
ctrl not crtl
```